# how to correct matlab Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context

Tags: matlab

```
function [output] = english2morse(text)

% Where a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 ...                                                                                                                                                                            space     numberals start here... 0 - 9                                                       specials characters start here: in this order| begining     . , ? ! : " ' =       end                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
definitions = {' .-' ' -...' ' -.-.' ' -..' ' .' ' ..-.' ' --.' ' ....' ' ..' ' .---' ' -.-' ' .-..' ' --' ' -.' ' ---' ' .--.' ' --.-' ' .-.' ' ...' ' -' ' ..-' ' ..-' ' .--' ' -..-' ' -.--' ' --..' '        '   '-----' '.----' '..---' '...--' '....-' '.....' '-....' '--...' '---..' '----.'     '.-.-.-' '--..--' '..--..' '..--.' '---...' '.-..-.' '.----.' '-...-'};


output = definitions(text);
end

clc
clear
i = 1;

% Asks user for txt, and checks to see if the input is valid, ifnot, get
% new user input, else break while loop and continue program exectution.

while i == 1

    disp('Program converts strings to morce code. ONLY ACCEPTS: A-Z a-z 0-9   , . , ? ! : " `')

    pause(1)

    text = input('Enter a string: ', 's');
    text = lower(text)
    disp('Checking to see if correct values entered.')
    converted = zeros(1, length(text))
    for x = 1:length(text)
        % for lowercase
        if text(x) >= 97 && text(x) <= 122

            % for numberals 0-9
            converted(x) = double(text(x) - 96);

            i = 0;
        elseif  text(x) >= 48 && text(x) <= 57
            converted(x) = text(x) - 20

            i = 0;
            % for special characters, listed above
        elseif text(x) == 46 ||  text(x) == 44 ||  text(x) == 63 ||  text(x) == 33 ||  text(x) == 58 ||  text(x) == 34 ||  text(x) == 39 ||  text(x) == 61
            switch text(x) == 46 ||  text(x) == 44 ||  text(x) == 63 ||  text(x) == 33 ||  text(x) == 58 ||  text(x) == 34 ||  text(x) == 39 ||  text(x) == 61
                case text(x) == 46
                    converted(x) = text(x) - 8
                case text(x) == 44
                    converted(x) = text(x) - 5
                case text(x) == 63
                    converted(x) = text(x) - 23
                case text(x) == 33
                    converted(x) = text(x) + 8
                case text(x) == 58
                    converted(x) = text(x) - 16
                case text(x) == 34
                    converted(x) = text(x) + 9
                case text(x) == 39
                    converted(x) = text(x) +5
                case text(x) == 61
                    converted(x) = text(x) - 16
            end

            i = 0;

        else

            i = 1;

        end

    end

end
disp(converted)
disp(english2morse(converted))
```

Comment: Where is this code? How are you running it?

Comment: Please explain your question or people wont know how to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please remove the following part from your script, and save it in a file named `english2morse.m`:

```
function [output] = english2morse(text)

% Where a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 ...                                                                                                                                                                            space     numberals start here... 0 - 9                                                       specials characters start here: in this order| begining     . , ? ! : " ' =       end                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
definitions = {' .-' ' -...' ' -.-.' ' -..' ' .' ' ..-.' ' --.' ' ....' ' ..' ' .---' ' -.-' ' .-..' ' --' ' -.' ' ---' ' .--.' ' --.-' ' .-.' ' ...' ' -' ' ..-' ' ..-' ' .--' ' -..-' ' -.--' ' --..' '        '   '-----' '.----' '..---' '...--' '....-' '.....' '-....' '--...' '---..' '----.'     '.-.-.-' '--..--' '..--..' '..--.' '---...' '.-..-.' '.----.' '-...-'};


output = definitions(text);
end
```

Save the script after removal, save the function after editing, run the script again.

**Explanation:** MATLAB makes a difference between *functions* and *scripts*.

A MATLAB code file in which the first non-comment keyword is `function` is (surprise!) a function, i.e. a piece of code that—usually—waits for some input, returns some output based on that, and does some stuff in between. All inputs, outputs and temporary data are created in a *function's workspace* of its own, every time the function is called.

A file that —excepting eventual comments—doesn't begin with `function` (or `classdef`) is a script, and is intended to be executed imediately, using whatever data is available in the *global workspace*, and storing its outputs in the same global workspace.

Now, MATLAB doesn't want to mix function definitions with scripts. That's why the function should be in its own file, and the script in its own file.